# What in the Salt causes it to fail in decryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography

The code below and in the Fiddle isn't for production, it is for educational purposes.  I do not want to fix anything, as I have a viable solution.  However, I would like to know why:

```
var password = "password";
var salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Length.ToString());
var secret = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
```

When the above is implemented, in the following method `FixedEncryptor` will work.

```
// Valid:
public static string FixedEncryptor(string content)
{
    var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    var plain = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
    var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
    using (var encrypt = cipher.CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                crypto.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
                crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
            }
}
```

However, if you implement:

```
var secret = new PasswordDeriveBytes("password",
     Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));
```

The code will suddenly produce:

> Run-time exception (line 70): Padding is invalid and cannot be
>   removed.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is
>   invalid and cannot be removed.]   at Crypt.Decryptor(String content):
>   line 70   at Program.Main(): line 17

As denoted in the following method:

```
// Invalid:
public static string Encryptor(string content)
{
    var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    var plain = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
    var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes("password", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));
    using (var encrypt = cipher.CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                crypto.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
                crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
            }
}
```

So why can one successfully decrypt, while the other doesn't decrypt correctly and produces the above error?

A Fiddle with a small example is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yjMe7G).

Comment: The two pieces of code are not equivalent - the first one is missing `ToString()` call.

Comment: @Greg Make a minimal [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) that re-creates the problem and post it here. You are unlikely to get help with the way your question is right now.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your posted code example your problem comes from the fact you are using two different salts.

In FixedEncryptor you use a salt of

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Length.ToString());
```

That encodes to be a byte array equal to `{ 56 }`, this is because `Length` returns `8` then calling ToString() on that returns the string "8" which you convert in to the ascii value 56.

In Encryptor you use a salt of

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password")
```

That encodes to be a byte array equal to `{ 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100}`, which is the ascii values of the characters "p", "a", "s", "s", "w", "o", "r", and "d".

The problem you are running in to is you only attempt to use `{ 56 }` in your decrypt function, so your problem comes down to **your encrypt function and your decrypt function are using two different salts**.

If I make a make a new `Decrypter` to use the same salt and password as `Encryptor` then make a separate `FixedDecryptor` to match the salt of `FixedEncryptor` everything will work fine

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var message = "Hello World!";
        var fixedCipherText = Crypt.FixedEncryptor(message);
        var cipherText = Crypt.Encryptor(message);
        Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
        Console.WriteLine(fixedCipherText);
        var plainText = Crypt.Decryptor(cipherText);
        var fixedPlainText = Crypt.FixedDecryptor(fixedCipherText);
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);
        Console.WriteLine(fixedPlainText);
    }
}

public static class Crypt
{
    private const string password = "password";
    private readonly static byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Length.ToString());
    public static string FixedEncryptor(string content)
    {
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        var plain = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
        var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
        using (var encrypt = cipher.CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            crypto.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
            crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static string Encryptor(string content)
    {
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        var plain = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
        var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes("password", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));
        using (var encrypt = cipher.CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            crypto.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
            crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static string FixedDecryptor(string content)
    {
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
        using (var decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            byte[] plain = new byte[encrypted.Length];
            int decrypted = crypto.Read(plain, 0, plain.Length);
            string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plain, 0, decrypted);
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static string Decryptor(string content)
    {
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        var key = new PasswordDeriveBytes("password", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password"));
        using (var decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)))
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            byte[] plain = new byte[encrypted.Length];
            int decrypted = crypto.Read(plain, 0, plain.Length);
            string data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plain, 0, decrypted);
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddel](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Va1dO) of the code.

However this still is not the "correct" way to do things. See [Sine Nomen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634968/80274) answer

Comment: I know it isn't the proper way, I saw that code and was intrigued by it then I noticed that peculiarity. So I thought I would ask why the inconsistency. It makes sense what you said about the salts being different.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the method by which you generate a salt is not secure at all; secondly, `PasswordDerivedBytes` is deprecated and you should be looking at its successor, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Try something like the following - note that this requires a few `using` statements: `System`, `System.IO`, `System.Security.Cryptography` and `System.Text`.

Simply encrypt the data with `Encrypt(PlainText, Password)` and decrypt it again with `Decrypt(EncryptedData, Password)`. The salt is rolled into the encrypted data as the first 16 bytes and it is completely random for each encryption/decryption round.

This code is part of my own open source password manager.

```
/*
 * Encryption/Decryption, based on AES256 and PBKDF2
 */
public string Encrypt (string plainText, string passPhrase, bool fast_encrypt = false)
{
    string result;
    using (Rijndael algR = Rijndael.Create ()) {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngC = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider ();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        rngC.GetBytes (iv);
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes derived = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes (passPhrase, iv, fast_encrypt ? 10 : 3000);
        algR.KeySize = 256;
        algR.BlockSize = 128;
        algR.Key = derived.GetBytes (32);
        algR.IV = iv;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ()) {
            memoryStream.Write (iv, 0, 16);
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStreamEncrypt = new CryptoStream (memoryStream, algR.CreateEncryptor (algR.Key, algR.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriterEncrypt = new StreamWriter (cryptoStreamEncrypt)) {
                    streamWriterEncrypt.Write (plainText);
                }
            }

            result = Convert.ToBase64String (memoryStream.ToArray ());
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public string Decrypt (string cipherText, string passPhrase, bool fast_decrypt = false)
{
    string result;
    using (Rijndael algR = Rijndael.Create ()) {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream (Convert.FromBase64String (cipherText))) {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            memoryStream.Read (iv, 0, 16);
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes derived = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes (passPhrase, iv, fast_decrypt ? 10 : 3000);
            algR.KeySize = 256;
            algR.BlockSize = 128;
            algR.Key = derived.GetBytes (32);
            algR.IV = iv;
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStreamDecrypt = new CryptoStream (memoryStream, algR.CreateDecryptor (algR.Key, algR.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                using (StreamReader streamReaderDecrypt = new StreamReader (cryptoStreamDecrypt)) {
                    result = streamReaderDecrypt.ReadToEnd ();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The code above isn't production as I stated in my question, it is for educational purposes.  What I want to know:

Why with those two different approaches to create the `salt` why does one cause a Stack Trace exception in decryption, while the other doesn't.

Comment: Then that makes the whole point of NOT using PasswordDerivedBytes even more important; educationally speaking, it is better practice to learn the proper method of doing things. Like with fixing a dent in your favourite desk; sure, you could paint over it so it APPEARS smooth but wouldn't you much rather just fix it properly?

Comment: @Greg because you only use one approach to create the salt when you decrypt. Your two approaches produces produce two different salts, but you use only one of those two different salts during your decryption processs.